# Equivalent method for putAll on SparseArray

Tags: java, android, data-structures, hashmap, sparse-matrix

I would like to know if there is an equivalent method to the *putAll* method available on HashMap class on the SparseArray class ?

I'm confused if I should use *append*, *put* or *setValueAt* and if it would give me the same result.

Is SparseArrayX.append(i,SparseArrayY.valueAt(i)) = MapX.put(MapY);  ?

Comment: See for yourself at the official Android guidelines. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html

Comment: Thanks, I should have been more specific in my question. What I would like to know is if there is a way to achieve the same thing using SparseArray, is that possible ? Maybe through iteration ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no putAll() method available to the SparseArray class. [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html)

```
append(int key, E value)
Puts a key/value pair into the array, optimizing for the case where the key is greater than all existing keys in the array.

put(int key, E value)
Adds a mapping from the specified key to the specified value, replacing the previous mapping from the specified key if there was one.

setValueAt(int index, E value)
Given an index in the range 0...size()-1, sets a new value for the indexth key-value mapping that this SparseArray stores.
```

Comment: Yup, so if I try something like this:                                                                                                                for(int i =0; i <SparseArrayY.size();i++){SparseArrayX.append(i,SparseArrayY.valueAt(i)) } will it give me the same result as putAll method ?

Comment: Yes, that is the way I would do it. This way you wont overwrite anything accidentally.

Comment: ummmm.. actually putAll of HashMap will override if needed : https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html#putAll(java.util.Map<? extends K, ? extends V>)